# SwiftUI Form and StackNavigationViewStyle run berserk

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a NavigationView with a `Form` containing a `Picker` and a `NavigationLink`, and want to use `navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())`. When doing a fresh launch in portrait mode it behaves as expected. But after rotating the device to landscape and back to portrait and tapping the NavigationLink it loads multiple copies of the destination view and then returns back to the original view, as seen here:

[UI gone berserk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tsb7x.gif)

This happens booth on physical device and in simulator.

If I remove `navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())` this problem doesn’t occur, but I would prefer to have it.

I’ve boiled down the problem to this code sample. This is run in a fresh SwiftUI project, with no changes made to the standard SceneDelegate.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            Form{

                NavigationLink(destination: DestinationView()) {
                    Text("NavigationLink")
                }

            }.navigationBarTitle("ContentView")

        }.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
    }
}

struct DestinationView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Destination")
            .navigationBarTitle("DestinationView")
    }
}
```

After rotating the device to landscape and back and then tapping the NavigationLink, this is what it looks like in the visual debugger:

[Visual debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImyoW.png)

There are duplicates of the view behind each other. With every rotation back and forth more are added.

I’ve googled and searched Stackoverflow without finding a solution.

Comment: It appears the defect is of `NavigationLink`in `Form`. Presence or absence of `Picker` does not matter - the issue is reproduced even with only on `NavigationLink` in `Form`, which in `NavigationView` of course. Tested on Xcode 11.2 / iOS 13.2.

Comment: Edited: Removed Picker and related code from sample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update: With Xcode 12 this bug is fixed.

With Xcode 11.3.1 there seems to be a bug in `Form`, making a new copy of the view with every orientation change of the device.

Sample code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
            Form{
                Text("Text")
            }
    }
}
```

Visual debugger at beginning, rotate left and then rotate right:

[image: Visual debugger]

A `Form` automatically adopts the `GroupedListStyle` and it seems that it’s actually there the bug is. Because a `List` with `GroupedListStyle` shows the same behaviour in the visual debugger.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        List{
            Text("Text")
        }.listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
    }
}
```

Comment: Same bug with Xcode 11.7... Any  workaround to make it works with `StackNavigationViewStyle()`?